# What shall be the logical conclusion out of the following?

Tags: logic

Each question has a main statement, followed by four statements labeled A,B,C and D. Choose the ordered pair of statements, where the fisrt statement implies the second, and the two statements are logically consistent with the main statement.

All irresponsible bosses shout if their workers do not fall in line.
(A) All irresponsible bosses do not shout.
(B ) Workers fall in line.
(C) Workers do not fall in line.
(D) All irresponsible bosses shout.

(a) AB
(b) BA
(c) CA
(d) none of these.

{since it's an "If A then B" type, answer should be (a) that is AB, but it's wrong; in answer key it shows (b) as an answer. I'm not able to understand why.

the two valid conclusions of 'if P then Q' statment are: Q'P' or PQ itself. 
So here: clause 'workers do not fall in line' is P since it's followed by word 'if' and clause 'all irresponsible bosses shout' becomes Q. 
So shouldn't the answer be BA from the options, i.e. all irresponsible bosses do not shout, workers fall in line?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't agree with you or your answer key.  The statement itself is CD, which isn't one of the options.  But the contrapositive also isn't one of the options, since the negation of "All irresponsible bosses shout" is "Not all irresponsible bosses shout" or "Some irresponsible bosses don't shout".  Those are different statements than "All irresponsible bosses don't shout", at least in English.

Comment: if you can look at the edit history, you'll see we may not be dealling with a question originally written in English. Something may have been lost in the translation, or in the editing.

Answer (score 0):

X if Y means if Y then X, so your axiom is $C \implies D$.  The contrapositive of that is $\lnot D \implies \lnot C$, which is $A \implies B$.  This would say the answer is a in agreement with you.

The wording of the question is poor.  It should say "the first statement implies the second based on the main statement."  All of $A,B,C,D$ are compatible with the main statement depending on the truth value of other statements in the list.